# How to change company name of my account in app store connect?

Tags: app-store-connect, apple-id

I created a business apple developer account for my company successfully but I put my name under company name accidentally. I wasn't aware of that tho. Now, Apple support keeps rejecting my app and they keep saying:

> The seller and company names associated with your app do not reflect the financial institute name "Company Name" in the app or its metadata, as required by Guideline 3.2.1(viii) of the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> We see as the seller name: Comapny Name
>
> And as the company name: Safeen Azad

I tried reviewing the App Testing Guide, which gives an overview of how to test your app to minimize the chances of issues occurring during review. There was no issue with my app.

I tried reviewing Designing for Real-World Networks, as all apps are reviewed on-device and in an environment that replicates real-world use of your app.

I tried testing my App on an IPv6-Only Network as suggested by Apple Support.

Unfortunately, Apple support cannot provide technical assistance and I don't know how to change the company name I literally tried everything!

Can anyone have any info of how I can change the company name (Account Holder Name) so that it will reflect my company name's financial institute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only Apple Developer Support can help you with changing your account's name: https://developer.apple.com/contact/